# Setting & saving a pointer in a certain class in parse.com with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform

I am trying to create two pointers to store in a class called appointments. One pointer is for a teacher & other for the student. I have used a global variable for selectedTeacherId in another event to store the selected teachers user id as a string. below is my code. I get an error message 400 bad request. Why isn't my pointers & class saving?

```
 $('#final-submit').on('click', function() {

  var day= $('div#apt-detail-time li span#day').text();
  var time= $('div#apt-detail-time li span#time').text();
  var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
  var currentUserId = currentUser.id;
   var userPointer = {
  __type: 'Pointer',
  className: '_User',
  objectId: currentUserId
}
var teacherPointer = {
  __type: 'Pointer',
  className: '_User',
  objectId: selectedTeacherId
}


   var appointment = Parse.Object.extend("Appoinments");
   var newAppointment = new appointment();

   newAppointment.set('day', day);
   newAppointment.set('time', time); 
   newAppointment.set('type', 'pending');
   newAppointment.set('student', userPointer);
   newAppointment.set('teacher', teacherPointer);
   newAppointment.save();
   });   `
```

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question..,

Comment: @Wain my code above doesn't work I get an error message. I am wondering if i'm creating the parse.com JavaScript pointers correctly or if I'm using them wrong

Comment: What is the error message? From which line of code?

Answer (score 0):

A few things may be causing your problems:

1. Where is `selectedTeacherId` coming from? It's not defined in your function. Depending on how this is implemented, this may be the cause of your error.
2. You spelled "Appointments" wrong in `var appointment = Parse.Object.extend("Appoinments");`
3. I recommend that you always pass a success and error callback to any `.save()` calls. You can check on the Parse Javascript SDK documentations for idiomatic examples of this. By passing success and error callbacks, if you get a bad request or other error, you will be able to invoke an `alert()` or `console.log()` function to display the cause of the errors. Furthermore, there are bugs that might cause you to make an infinite number of requests to Parse. Because Parse charges money above a certain rate of requests, you may be charged unintentionally if you are not careful.